# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\wamp\www\Cocolani\php\req\checkusername.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql

I get an error in my file "checkusername.php".

The error I get is:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   C:\wamp\www\Cocolani\php\req\checkusername.php on line 4

**There is a "checkusername.php" file :**

```
<?php
    include_once("../../includes/db.php");
    include_once("settings.php");
    $db = new database($obj->get("db_name"), $obj->get("db_server"), $obj->get("db_user"), $obj->get("db_password"), $obj->get("url_root"));

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : "";
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';
    $birthdate = isset($_POST['birthdate']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate']) : "";
    $firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']) : "";
    $lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']) : "";
    $sex = isset($_POST['sex']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']) : "";
    $tribeid = isset($_POST['clan']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['clan']) : "";
    $mask = isset($_POST['mask']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['mask']) : "";
    $mask_color = isset($_POST['maskcl']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['maskcl']) : "";
    $lang_id = isset($_POST['lang_id']) ? addslashes($_POST['lang_id']) : 0;
    $error = '';

   // get language suffix 
     if ($lang_id != 0) {
     $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_extra_langs` WHERE id='{$lang_id}'");
     $res = $db->loadResult();
     $lang = "_".$res->lang;
   } else $lang = "";  

   $reg_ok = true;

   $db->setQuery("SELECT one_email_per_registration FROM `cc_def_settings`");
   $res = $db->loadResult();
   $one_registration_per_email = ($res->one_email_per_registration == 1);

   $email_check_ok = true;
   if ($one_registration_per_email == true) {
     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM `cc_user` WHERE email='{$email}'"; // for several registrations per one email address -- no check  
       $db->setQuery($sql);
       $res1 = $db->loadResult();
       $email_check_ok = $res1->counter == "0";
     }
   if ($email_check_ok == false) { 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='DUPLICATED_EMAIL'"; 
     $db->setQuery($sql);
     $res = $db->loadResult();
       echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
       $reg_ok = false;
   }

    /*if ($reg_ok && $email != '') {
      // get number of already registered number of registrations with this email address          
      $sql = "SELECT count(*) as registered_num_emails FROM `cc_user` WHERE email='{$email}'";
      $query = $db->setQuery($sql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
      $registered_num_emails = $row->registered_num_emails;

      $sql = "SELECT max_num_account_per_email from `cc_def_settings`";
      $query = $db->setQuery($sql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

      // it's possible to create new registration using this email address
      if ($registered_num_emails >= $row->max_num_account_per_email) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='MAX_NUM_REGISTRATION_REACHED'"; 
        $db->setQuery($sql);
        $res = $db->loadResult();
          echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
        $reg_ok = false;
      }
    }*/
////////
//     echo 'error=111';
//     $reg_ok = false;
////////


     if ($reg_ok) {
     // check for swear words     
     $db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as counter from `cc_swear_words` where INSTR('".$username."', `name`)");
     $res2 = $db->loadResult();
     if ((int)($res2->counter) > 0) { // swear word founded!
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='USERNAME_NOT_PERMITTED'";
       $db->setQuery($sql);
       $res = $db->loadResult();
       echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
       $reg_ok = false;
     }
   } 

     if ($reg_ok) {
     // first check there is no username with this name already registered.
     $db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM `cc_user` WHERE username='".$username."'");
     $res = $db->loadResult();
     if ((int)($res->counter) > 0) { // swear word founded!
       // get warning message from db
       $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc_translations` WHERE caption='USERNAME_IN_USE'");
       $res = $db->loadResult();
       echo 'error='.urlencode($res->{"name".$lang});
       $reg_ok = false;
       }
   }

   if ($reg_ok) echo 'result=true';  

?>
```

**The problem on line 4 which is :**

```
$db = new database($obj->get("db_name"), $obj->get("db_server"), $obj->get("db_user"), $obj->get("db_password"), $obj->get("url_root"));
```

**There is a "settings.php" :**

```
<?php

    $db_server = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_password = "pass1234";
    $db_name = "cocolani_battle"; 
    $appsecret = "80f730a73ac60417c36c341bc975f6f1";    

    $connect = mysqli_connect("$db_server","$db_user","$db_password","$db_name");


?>
```

**and there is a "db.php" :**

```
<?php

/*
Usage
$db = new database($dbname);

for selects:
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `table`")
$resultArray = $db->loadResults();

$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `primary_id` = '1'");
$resultObject = $db->loadResult();

for inserts:
$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `example`) VALUES ('1', 'abc')");
if (!$db->runQuery()) {
    echo $db->getError();
}
*/


class database {
    var $_debug = 0;
    var $_sql = '';
    var $_error = '';
    var $_prefix = '';

    var $_numrows = 0;

    var $_DBhost = 'localhost';
    var $_DBuser = "root";
    var $_DBpass = "pass1234";
    var $_DBname = "cocolani_battle";
    var $url_root = "localhost/cocolani";

    public function __construct($dbname = 'cocolani_battle', $dbuser = 'root', $dbpsw = 'pass1234', $dbhost = 'localhost', $urlroot = 'localhost/cocolani') {

            $this->_DBname = 'cocolani_battle';
            $this->_DBuser = 'root';
            $this->_DBpass = 'pass1234';
            $this->url_root = 'localhost/cocolani';
            $this->_DBhost = 'localhost';

        $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this->_DBhost, $this->_DBuser, $this->_DBpass) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
        mysqli_select_db($this->_connection, $this->_DBname) or die("Select DB Error: ".mysqli_error());

    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->_connection);
    }

    function debug($debug_level) {
        $this->_debug = intval($debug_level);   
    }

    function setQuery($sql) {
        /* queries are given in the form of #__table need to replace that with the prefix */
        $this->_sql = str_replace('#__', $this->_prefix.'_', $sql);
    }

    function getQuery() {
        return "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars( $this->_sql) . "</pre>";
    }

    function prepareStatement($sql) {
        $this->sql = mysqli_prepare($this->_connection, $sql);
        return $this->sql;
    }

    function runQuery($num_rows=0) {
        mysqli_select_db($this->_connection, $this->_DBname) or die("Select DB Error: ".mysqli_error());

        $this->_numrows = 0;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $this->_sql);
        if ($this->_debug > 1) echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars( $this->_sql) . "</pre>";

        if (!$result) {
            $this->_error = mysqli_error($this->_connection);
            if ($this->_debug) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $this->getQuery() . $this->_error;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if ($num_rows) {
            $this->_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /* Retrieve Mysql insert id */
    function mysqlInsertID() {
        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id();
        return $insert_id;
    }

/* Escapes special characters while inserting to db */
    function db_input($string) {
      if (is_array($string)) {
          $retArray = array();
          foreach($string as $key => $value) {
              $value = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : $value);
              $retArray[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
          }
          return $retArray;
      } else {
          $string = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($string) : $string);
          return mysqli_real_escape_string($string);

      }
    }


    function getError() {
        return $this->_error;
    }
    /* Load results into csv formatted string */
    function loadCsv() {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            return null;
        }

        $csv_string = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
            $line = '';
            foreach( $row as $value ) {                                            
                if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ) {
                    $value = ",";
                } else { 
                    $value = $value. ",";
                    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $line = substr($line, 0, -1);
            $csv_string .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
        }
        $csv_string = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $csv_string );
            //$csv_string .= implode(",", $row) . "\n";
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $csv_string;
    }

    /* Load multiple results */
    function loadResults($key='' ) {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            return null;
        }
        $array = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
            if ($key) {
                $array[strtolower($row->$key)] = $row;
            } else {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $array;
    }

    function loadResult() {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            if ($this->_debug) echo 'Error: ' . $this->_error;
            return null;
        }
        $row = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $row;
    }

    /* Load a result field into an array */
    function loadArray() {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            return null;
        }
        $array = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
            $array[] = $row[0];
        }
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $array;
    }

    /* Load a row into an associative an array */
    function loadAssoc() {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            return null;
        }
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $row;
    }

    /* Return one field */
    function loadField() {
        if (!($res = $this->runQuery())) {
            return null;
        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
            $field = $row[0];
        }
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $field;
    }

}

  /*if ($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == '127.0.0.1') {
    $url_root = "http://cocolani.localhost";
  } else {
    $url_root = "http://dev.cocolani.com";
  }*/


?>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You don't have `$obj` defined anywhere.

Comment: Aha Ok , So what shall I do ?

Comment: Just use the variables you defined in the settings file. Or hard-code it into your database class if you're not going to be using different settings.

Comment: can you do that and give me the code please ?
Sorry to disturb you

Comment: Please see read **[ask]** AND **[mcve]**. Also you might want to do your homework with your class mates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39149350 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/39130469 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/39108844

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can either use the variables you defined in your settings.php:

```
$db = new database($db_name, $db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_urlroot); // You didn't define $db_urlroot anywhere, but you can define it
```

OR hard-code it into your class. You're not using the variables you pass in anyway, so there's no need to ask for them.

```
public function __construct() {
```

Comment: Thank you . it's work now can you give me your account on facebook to contact you ?

Comment: Sorry, for security reasons, that information is private.

Comment: oh :( ok .. there is some problems in other files can you help me in it

Comment: Ask another question on here, if I don't answer it, someone else will.

Comment: I have " feeder.php " the problem in it :

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: lang in C:\wamp\www\Cocolani\php\req\feeder.php on line 12

th line12 is : $mylang = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lang"]);
so please help me